# Why use a const member function?

Tags: c++, function, class, constants, function-qualifier

i'm trying to understand class getters and setters functions...

My question is:
If i design a function that just only get a state from its class (a "getter" function), why mark it as "const member function"?
I mean, why use a const member function if my function is designed to not change any proprieties of its class?
i don't understand please :(

for example:

```
int GetValue() {return a_private_variable;}
```

and

```
int GetValue() const {return a_private_variable;}
```

what is the real difference?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

When you declare a member function as `const`, like in

```
int GetValue() const;
```

then you tell the compiler that it will not modify anything in the object.

That also means you can call the member function on constant object. If you don't have the `const` modifier then you can't call it on an object that has been defined as `const`. You can still call `const` member functions on non-constant objects.

Also note that the `const` modifier is part of the member function signature, which means you can overload it with a non-const function. That is you can have

```
int GetValue() const;
int GetValue();
```

in the same class.

Answer (score 13):

`const` can show up in three different places in C++.

Example 1:

`const Object obj1;`

- obj1 is a `const` object. Meaning that you can not change anything on this object. This object can only call `const` member functions like

> int GetValue() const {return a_private_variable;}

Example 2:

`int myMethod() const {//do something}`

- This is a `const` method. It would be a `const` member function if it is declared inside of a class. These are the types of methods that `const` variables can call.

Example 3:

`int myMethod(const Object &x) {//do something with x}`

- This is a method that takes a `const` parameter. This means that the logic inside `myMethod` is not allowed to change anything to do with `x`. Also note the parameter is being passed by reference not by copy. I like to think of this as a read only type of method.

When you are developing software that will be used by others; it is a good idea to not let them break things they don't know they should not break. In this case you can constrain variables, methods, and parameters to be `const` to guaranteed that the contract is upheld. I tried to summarize the main ideas I learned in college, but there are many resources online around `const` in C++. Check out this [link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/810-const-class-objects-and-member-functions/) if you would like to know more. Also it is possible that I remembered somethings incorrectly as I have not been in the C/C++ realm for a while.

Comment: Your answer is very detailed, thank you ^_^

Answer (score 0):

A const instance of a class can only call const functions.

Having a const instance of a class is useful for making your programs more stable since then you can't modify the instance by accident.

In your case the functions do exactly the same thing, but it doesn't have to be that way.

Comment: Member functions declared as `const` can be called on non-constant objects.

Comment: thank you, I had this the wrong way round. Your answer is much nicer than mine.