# When and why would I use a constant function in C++

Tags: c++, function, constants

**Edit**: From @Jeremy Friesner's answer, he provides another view point that [Why use a const member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137928/why-use-a-const-member-function) & [semantics of a const member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98705/what-are-the-semantics-of-a-const-member-function) don't cover. It can improve clarity and disambiguous your code. People can have a brief idea of what this function is supposed to do or not do at the first glance. Very useful especially in working with others.

I come across the constant function lately.

It says:

> Constant functions are those have denied permission when attempting
> to change the member variables of their classes.

My questions are

> In a programmer perspective, if you don't want a function being able to change member
> variables, why not just moving the parts responsible for changing variables outside
> of the function at the first place? (e.g using another function)

> What/when are some practical moments of having the neediness to use a constant
> function?

Appreciate any answers

```
class Foo 
{
public:
    int x = 0;
    int Bar(int arg) const
    {
        x++; // fails
        return x; // okay
    }
};
```

Comment: In one case, if others has a non const object/iterator and they can't call a const function.

Comment: See [Why use a const member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137928/why-use-a-const-member-function) and [Semantics of const member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98705/what-are-the-semantics-of-a-const-member-function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of `const`-tagged methods isn't to prevent the programmer from *intentionally* modifying member variables, but rather to allow the compiler to assist the programmer by producing a compile-time error when the programmer *accidentally* modifies a member-variable.  This is useful because it's much easier and quicker to correct a compile-time error than to chase down a run-time misbehavior through manual testing.

The `const` tag also assists later programmers who are reading the class's header file by helping them quickly understand what a method does or does not do.  For example, if you see this in a class declaration:

```
class MyClass
{
   [...]

   int CalculateTheValue();
```

... you might ask yourself, "does calling `CalculateTheValue()` change the state of the `MyClass` object?"  With a name like `CalculateTheValue()` it seems like it shouldn't, but there's no way to know for sure without finding the corresponding `.cpp` file and reading through the code that implements that method... which is a tedious and error-prone way to do things.

On the other hand, if you see this:

```
class MyClass
{
   [...]

   int CalculateTheValue() const;
```

... then you know *right away* that `CalculateTheValue()` will not modify the `MyClass` object you call it on, because it says so in the declaration.  (if it did try to modify the `MyClass` object, the code wouldn't compile; so if the code compiled, we know it doesn't modify it)